# Specify x-axis labels in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a stackedAreaChart in d3.js

X-axis labels are 9 dates which I have formatted using tickFormat method. However, I want chart to take each date. Currently it takes every 2nd date.

```
var dates = ["Jun 07","Jun 08","Jun 09","Jun 10","Jun 11","Jun 12","Jun 13"];
                chart.xAxis.ticks(9);
                chart.xAxis
                    .tickFormat(function(d,e,f) {
                        if(d===1||d==7){
                            return ''
                        }
                        return dates[d-1];
                    });
```

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Set the tick values explicitly: `chart.tickValues(dates)`

Comment: Already tried. Gives chart.ticksValues is not a function.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yes. Actually it was other developer's code, which I got to fix and maintain. He is using nvd3.

Comment: Right, use `chart.xAxis.tickValues(dates)`.